# Size of custom progress dialog with animation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, themes, progress-bar

When the start of a app development i create a custom progress dialog which having an animation. But in further development i change some themes in that app. But have no change in code for this progress bar. But now that progress  dialog is not showing with required width and height. is any change in theme effect the width and height of dialog view. 
The theme for MainActivity is-

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And for AuthActivity and Splash is

```
<style name="fullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

And theme used for progress dialogue is-

```
 <style name="NewDialog" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

That fullScreen theme is also given to a fullscreen video dialog inside mainActivity. And code for progress dialogue is -

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (dialog == null)
            dialog = Dialog(this, R.style.NewDialog)
    }
fun showProgressDialog() {
    val ANIM_TIME: Long = 3000
    dialog!!.setCancelable(false)
    dialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialoge)
    val img = dialog!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_image)
    var i = 0
    val r= object:Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            img.setImageResource(mThumbIds[i])
            i++
            if(i >= mThumbIds.size){
                i = 0
            }
            img.postDelayed(this,50)
        }
    }
    img.postDelayed(r,50)
    val anim = CircularRotateAnimation(img, 150f)
    anim.duration = ANIM_TIME
    anim.repeatCount = 50
    img.animation = anim
    if (dialog!!.isShowing) {
        dialog!!.dismiss()
    }
    dialog!!.show()
}
```

Is their any way to effect the theme of Another dialog or theme of activity to this progress dialog?. Also for all activity this progress dialog is broken. Can anyone explain way to fix that size of progress dialog without changing that theme for activity. Also tried to give width and height using layoutparams.
My manifest is -

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.dnbs.consumerapp">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <other permimssions>
        <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
                      android:theme="@style/fullScreenDialog">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".activities.AuthenticationActivity"
                      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                      android:configChanges="orientation"
                      android:theme="@style/fullScreenDialog"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest

Comment: ok i will edit my question and add manifest

Comment: when i removed android:hardwareAccelerated="false" from application tag it is working, anyone can say why it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a the solution.By mistake i added `hardwareAccelerated = false` inside application tag. From more study about that i found that it will effect custom views. for all devices above or equals API level 14 `hardwareAccelerated` is turn on by default. And if we are using  standard views and Drawables, turning it on globally should not cause any adverse drawing effects. so I made change in my manifest as follows-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.dnbs.consumerapp">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <other permimssions>
        <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:largeHeap="true"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
                      android:theme="@style/fullScreenDialog">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".activities.AuthenticationActivity"
                      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                      android:configChanges="orientation"
                      android:theme="@style/fullScreenDialog"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

I got solution from [This link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel)